# How to fill variable with values by service (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

My variable has no value after calling the service. I defined the success function as a separate function and called it in the `.then()` method, here's the code:

```
// Code inside the Ctrl:
var successData = null;
vm.fillVar = null;
vm.loadData = loadData;

// service func
function loadData() {
   return $timeout(function () {
      vm.fillVar = vm.fillVar || [];

      if (vm.fillVar == undefined || vm.fillVar.length == 0) {
          CrudSvc.GetAllData().$promise.then(success, error);

          console.log('Success Variable: ', successData); //--> here, the successData variable contains no data
          vm.fillVar = successData;
          console.log('fillVar for the view: ', vm.fillVar); //--> fillVar is empty, why??
      }
   }, 500);
}

// success func
function success(res) {
   console.log('var res: ', res); //--> res contains data
   successData = res;
   console.log('success func: ', successData); //--> the variable contains data
}
```

I don't understand why the successData variable is empty after calling the success function. It is a bit confusing... Has anyone a solution for this issue?

Comment: can u post the code for CrudSvc.GetAllData()

Comment: Why don't you just set `vm.fillVar` inside `function success`  and avoid using `successData` variable

Comment: you are expecting synchronous execution out of asynchronous call. Hope you know the core JS

Comment: @sand Because I want to use the `success`-method also for other services in the same controller and it is better to read.

Comment: @yuro check my answer, it should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is async `CrudSvc.GetAllData().$promise.then(success, error);` so if you want to execute something after that you should change your code to:

```
CrudSvc.GetAllData().$promise.then(success, error).then(function(){
     // this code is executed after all the previous code is done and succeed
     console.log('Success Variable: ', successData); 
     vm.fillVar = successData;
     console.log('fillVar for the view: ', vm.fillVar); 
});
```

You can read about `then` chaining [**HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)

> The then method returns a Promise which allows for method chaining.

**EDIT**

If you want to handle error situation simply use `reject` function like this:

```
CrudSvc.GetAllData().$promise.then(success, error).then(function(){
     // this code is executed if previous success 
}, function(){
     // this code is executed if previous error
}); // This is how you do further error handling via this approach
```

Comment: What is, when an error is expected? I defined the err variables in error function, which will show the error in the view immediately.

Comment: thanks for your support. Currently is this a good approach :)

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that this code helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Code inside the Ctrl:
var successData = null;
vm.fillVar = null;
vm.loadData = loadData;

// service func
function loadData() {
   return $timeout(function () {
      vm.fillVar = vm.fillVar || [];

      if (vm.fillVar == undefined || vm.fillVar.length == 0) {
          CrudSvc.GetAllData().$promise.then(function(response) {
successData = response;
    console.log('Success Variable: ', successData); //--> here, the success variable now contains no data
          vm.fillVar = successData;
          console.log('fillVar for the view: ', vm.fillVar); //--> fillVar is empty, why??
}, function(error) {
});


      }
   }, 500);
}
```

Comment: That solution I already know. But not the expected solution I am looking for. However thanks for your support :)